# Maintain value semantics in Swift struct, which contains object reference

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a Swift struct which contains an object for internal storage. How can I make sure the struct has value semantics?

```
public struct Times {
    private let times = NSMutableIndexSet()

    mutating func addTimeRange(openTime: Int, closeTime: Int) {
        self.times.addIndexesInRange(NSRange(location: openTime, length: closeTime - openTime))
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the guidelines for when to choose a struct rather than a class is "Any properties stored by the structure are themselves value types, which would also be expected to be copied rather than referenced.". See also https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Swift 3 Update**

Swift 3 includes value types for many types from the Foundation framework. There is now an IndexSet struct, which bridges to NSIndexSet. The internal implementation is similar to the Swift 2 solution below.

For more information on the new Foundation value types see: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0069-swift-mutability-for-foundation.md

**Old approach in Swift 2**

The copy-on-write approach is the right solution. However, it is not necessary to create a copy of the NSMutableIndexSet, if only one struct instance references it. Swift provides a global function called `isUniquelyReferencedNonObjC()` to determine if a pure Swift object is only referenced once.

Since we cannot use this function with Objective-C classes, we need to wrap NSMutableIndexSet in a Swift class.

```
public struct Times {
    private final class MutableIndexSetWrapper {
        private let mutableIndexSet: NSMutableIndexSet

        init(indexSet: NSMutableIndexSet) {
            self.mutableIndexSet = indexSet
        }

        init() {
            self.mutableIndexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
        }
    }

    private let times = MutableIndexSetWrapper()

    mutating func addTimeRange(openTime: Int, closeTime: Int) {
        // Make sure our index set is only referenced by this struct instance
        if !isUniquelyReferencedNonObjC(&self.times) {
            self.times = MutableIndexSetWrapper(indexSet: NSMutableIndexSet(indexSet: self.times.mutableIndexSet))
        }

        let range = NSRange(location: openTime, length: closeTime - openTime)

        self.times.mutableIndexSet.addIndexesInRange(range)
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't guarantee that the wrapped index set isn't multiply referenced.

Comment: That is not an issue. This is the same technique Apple uses internally for Swift's Array, Dictionary, etc. See this post for more information: http://chris.eidhof.nl/posts/struct-semantics-in-swift.html

Comment: It is exactly the issue you asked about in your original question. If the wrapped index set is a mutable index set, the problem you are trying to solve remains unsolved - it can _possibly_ be mutated behind your back. The solution is the solution I gave: use an NSIndexSet.

Comment: MutableIndexSetWrapper is a private class and the wrapped NSMutableIndexSet is never exposed publicly. That's why it cannot be changed behind your back.

Comment: I understand that that's what you are hoping. But things like privacy are contractual; it is possible that this privacy will be violated. What you're doing will work if everyone is well-behaved - but of course, that would be true even without the privacy! There is a difference between hope and guarantee. Your approach is a hope. My approach is a guarantee.

Answer (score 3):

Store an NSIndexSet instead of an NSMutableIndexSet. That is exactly why the immutable superclass exists.

```
public struct Times {
    private var times = NSIndexSet()
    mutating func addTimeRange(openTime: Int, closeTime: Int) {
        let t = NSMutableIndexSet(indexSet:self.times)
        t.addIndexesInRange(NSRange(location: openTime, length: closeTime - openTime))
        self.times = NSIndexSet(indexSet:t)
    }
}
```

If this were a class instead of a struct, you could cause the last step to be performed automatically by declaring `times` as `@NSCopying` and then just using simple assignment:

```
public class Times {
    @NSCopying private var times = NSIndexSet()
    func addTimeRange(openTime: Int, closeTime: Int) {
        let t = NSMutableIndexSet(indexSet:self.times)
        t.addIndexesInRange(NSRange(location: openTime, length: closeTime - openTime))
        self.times = t // ensure immutable copy
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, matt. This kind of solution is also mentioned in the WWDC 2015 talk "Building Better Apps with Value Types in Swift" https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=414 starting at about 30 minutes. However, it is not necessary to create an immutable copy of the mutable index set. So, your last line could just be self.times = indexSet. Which saves another object creation.

Comment: "However, it is not necessary to create an immutable copy of the mutable index set" I think it is.

Answer (score 1):

It might be an option to use Swift's native `Set` type which has value-semantics built in since it is a struct itself.

```
public struct Times {
    private var times = Set<Int>()
    mutating func addTimeRange(openTime: Int, closeTime: Int) {
        (openTime ..< closeTime).map({ index -> Void in self.times.insert(index) })
    }
}

let t1 = Times()
var t2 = t1
t2.addTimeRange(0, closeTime: 3)

println(t1.times) // []
println(t2.times) // [2, 0, 1]
```